# How can I fish?

Tags: pixel-piracy

I have used a Fishing Book on a crew member. Also, I bought a Fishing Rod and equipped it (same guy), but the crew member doesn't start fishing.

How can I get a crew member to fish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Factors can influence the npc.

For example if you play on higher difficulties their character traits can also interfere with them cleaning/fishing.

A lazy pirate wont fish as much as a workaholic for example and an ex-model doesn't make for a good cleaning guy

And then there's the priorities of all the traits he has, that can also influence the behavior. For example cleaning + fishing does not work at all. Only either or works with those 2 traits from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The crew member should start fishing, following what you did. However, they can prefer other duties (if they have duties skills). A solution is to give the fisher only the fishing skill, or to bring them away from the ship (they can fish on a beach, or from enemy ships).